# Mapping three columns of sql to php arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have this MySQL table where I have four columns: location_id, location_name, address, city

I need to make two dropdowns, where the first drop down is the city name. So, if there are 10 cities with all same name, the dropdown should only have 1 city. Upon selecting that city, corresponding location name should come to the next dropdown - location name. Upon selecting the location name dropdown, its corresponding address to be displayed.

One of my logic to do was: 
Select all the distinct city from the database. With another query, select all the information.

Query: 
`SELECT distinct(city) from locations;` 
This would give me all the different city names.

`SELECT * from locations;` 
All the required data

Make an array, where key will be the city name, and location details as an array. Something like this

```
 Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [location_id] => 27
            [location_name] => ANSND
            [address] => some street 1
            [city] => NYC
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [location_id] => 809
            [location_name] => ANBC
            [address] => some street 1
            [city] => NYC
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [location_id] => 810
            [location_name] => dasddsdss
            [address] => some street 1
            [city] => Calif
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [location_id] => 811
            [location_name] => testing 6 feb
            [address] => some street 1
            [city] => Calif
        )

)
```

How can I do this in PHP?

```
Array
(
    [NYC] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [location_id] => 27
                    [location_name] => ANSND
                    [city] => NYC
                    [address] => some street 1 

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [location_id] => 809
                    [location_name] => ANBC
                    [city] => NYC
                    [address] => fsff
                )

        )

    [Calif] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [location_id] => 810
                    [location_name] => dasddsdss
                    [city] => Calif
                    [address] => some street 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [location_id] => 811
                    [location_name] => testing 6 feb
                    [city] => Calif
                    [address] => some street 1
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: What is your query ? What is your problem please explain in detial.

Comment: Can you show 10 data of table 'location' ?

Comment: Where is address field ?

Comment: Try following answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $results = array(); // it will be your resulted array

    $data_locations = array(); // lets say it is your data list of location table

    foreach( $data_locations as $location )
    {
        $results[$location->city][] = array(
            'location_name' =>$location->location_name; 
            'address' =>$location->address; 
        )
    }

    echo "<pre>"; print_r( $results ); die;
?>
```